# What does "if this is all going somewhere, get to it already" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

[Source](http://fmovies.to/film/manhattan-night.rk1y/rjmv9m)

> Girl:You grateful you landed a job that pays you to stare at people?
>
> Boy:I deal with bullshitters all day. But I'm on my own time here, so, if **this is all going somewhere, get to it already.**

Also what he's saying, "I get to it already or You get to it already"? This is subtitled in the video at 7:43.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that prior to this excerpt, she's asking about his job. It would appear that she is interested in the details of his job, but he becomes tired of all the questions. He suspects she isn't truly interested in his job and that she has a different reason for asking him questions, an ulterior motive. So he wants her to [get to the point](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+to+the+point), the real reason she is talking to him. This is what he means by

> if this is all going somewhere

where *somewhere* refers to her real reason for talking to him: *if you have a real/different reason for talking to me*.

> get to it already

means *get to it soon/now*, or *tell me soon/now*.  So all together, it would mean something like

> if you have a different reason for talking to me, tell me now.

Notice that *get to it* refers to **her**. He wants her to get to it. In terms of the options **you** that gave, *you* get to it already, not *I* get to it already. I don't mean to suggest that either is grammatical since, in this case, *get to it* is an imperative. He is commanding her to *get to* the point: *tell me now*.

Comment: +1 -- @AnubhavSingh About another minor point between *I/you get to it already*, it's *you get to it already* in that line.

Answer (score 2):

**get to it** has no subject (**I** or **you**): this indicates that it is an imperative- and order or command, like **give it to me!**. He is telling the girl [to get to the point](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+to+the+point) - to explain what she wants.

The [already](http://www.nytimes.com/1998/10/25/magazine/on-language-enough-already-what-am-i-chopped-liver.html) at the end of the sentence is an American-Jewish way of speaking, which comes via Yiddish from the German word **schon**. It gives an additional sense of urgency to the sentence.

Comment: "is it is an American-Jewish way" means "is an American-Jewish way"? Did you do it intensionally?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh, I fixed that.